# DWORD_PTR в указатель объекта

Tags: c++

В ходе программы я запаковываю указатель на объект в `DWORD_PTR((DWORD_PTR)Temp)`.

```
DWORD_PTR test = (DWORD_PTR)Temp;// Temp = *Test
```

Когда впоследствии я пытаюсь извлечь этот указатель таким образом

```
Test * test = dynamic_cast<Dir *>(test)
```

Мне выдаётся ошибка `the operand of pointer dynamic_cast must be a pointer to a complete class type`. Я не могу определить в чём ошибка. Хотя я могу успешно выполнить

```
Test* fd = dynamic_cast<Test*>(*begin)// Где begin содержит в себе указатель на Test
```

Comment: Test* foo = (Test*)bar; - такое приведение указателей пробовали?

Comment: Нет. Только что попробовал, сработало. Но вопрос почему же dynamic_cast не смог его привести у нужному типу.

Comment: Пока я не вкурил указатели я тоже пробовал *_cast, но после этого целых 16 лет ни разу их не использовал. Так что не могу сказать в чем именно там проблема.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов большое спасибо за помощь. Просто само по себе интересно почему cast не сработал. Вроде он должен отрабатывать но вот не отработал...

Comment: @Валентин Чикунов  Начнем с того, что в этом предложении Test * test = dynamic_cast<Dir *>(test): в правой части используется только что объявленный идентификатор, который не имеет валидного значения. Такое впечатление, что вы сами не понимаете, что вы делаете. Приведите минимальный пример, который можно запустить на компиляции и воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow это был ради примера сам код выглядит так
Dir* fd = getDir();//где getDir возвращает *Dir 
DWORD_PTR tmpDir = (DWORD_PTR)fd;
Dir * test = dynamic_cast<Dir *>(tmpDir);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас имеется код вроде такого кода

```
Dir* fd = getDir();//где getDir возвращает *Dir 
DWORD_PTR tmpDir = (DWORD_PTR)fd;
```

То используйте [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

```
Dir * test = reinterpret_cast<Dir *>(tmpDir);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но ведь reinterpret_cast не безопасен по своей сути.  
Получается что когда я запаковываю объект в DWORD_PTR он выпадает из цепочки наследования?

Comment: @Валентин Чикунов Указатель типа DWORD_PTR, как я понимаю, ни в какой цепочки полиморфного наследования не участвует.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение. Благодарю за помощь